# Value error when using SUM with a concatenate but works fine if manually type the exact same text

Tags: excel, sum, concatenation

I am having a problem trying to use the SUM function with the inside of the function obtained using the concatenate function. I have been trying to get the result I am wanting by rewriting the function in as many different ways as I can think of.

I am using this workbook to keep track and check for errors in paychecks. I have a sheet called Summation that shows the information from the last paycheck received and then then making some calculation using information from each check. Each check is in it's own sheet titled CheckMMDDYY format and each sheet is formatted the same. The Summation sheet is at the beginning and each check follows behind it.

I have a function LASTSHEET() that gets the name of the last sheet and returns it as a string. I also have a function NEXTSHEET() that gets the name of the next sheet and return it as a string.

I have in cell S2 LASTSHEET() and in cell S4 NEXTSHEET() so that it displays the name of the first check and the name of the last check.

What I am trying to do is sum data pulled from all the sheet and be dynamic so that I can simply add sheets at the end for each new check.

If I manually type the name of sheets the function =SUM(CheckMMDDYY:CheckMMDDYY!E7) works fine.

But if I use =SUM((CONCATENATE(S2,":",S4,"!E7"))) it gives me the #VALUE! error.
Even though if I simply put the concatenate portion in it's own cell it comes up with the exact same string as what's in the manually typed string.

Can anyone explain what the problem is and how I can fix it or a better way of doing this? I have tried many different formulas and this is the simplest way I've come up with. I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

I am using Excel 2013. I can post screenshots or the code for for the functions if needed, Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the `INDIRECT` function, which lets you substitute text for arguments like this.

Comment: Adding INDIRECT outside the CONCATENATE function function I have just changes the error to #REF! Adding it out the SUM function still get the #VALUE! error from the SUM function.

I have tried different combination of functions that I can think of and using INDIRECT but I run into either a #REF! error or #VALUE! error.

Comment: You are right. Although `INDIRECT` works with one sheet name, I also get a #REF when trying to work with a span of sheets using ":". My apologies for assuming that would work. The way this problem is typically solved is to use two empty hidden sheets to "bracket" the ones being summed. See this Peter Albert SO answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14717600/293078

Comment: Ah, yeah I happened to think of that at the end. I will probably just stick with that method. It was just driving me nuts since every combination of functions was giving me the same 2 errors. Does it just have problems since it's two dynamic names? I thought it was odd that it was having problems even though it came up with the correct information.